# First law of thermodynamics: External or internal pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, energy-conservation

When only pressure-volume work is done, the first law of thermodyanamics is given by:

$$ \Delta U = Q + P \Delta V $$

However, it isn't clear to me when to use internal or external pressure. How does it make sense to use external pressure to a change in internal energy?

Comment: $P\Delta V$ terms stand for the work done on/by the system. So, the net work would be difference between work done by the environment to the system by the external pressure and the work done by the system to the environment by the internal pressure.

Comment: Your relation is incorrect. It should read $\Delta U = Q - P\Delta V$. As for your question, it has already been answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/531922/

Comment: If the piston is massless, then the external and internal pressures have to match.  It's just that, in an irreversible process, you can't use the equation of state (e.g., the ideal gas law) to get the internal pressure.  Then what?  Your only choice is to use the external pressure (if you know it).